# Mapping Python dictionary with multiple keys into dataframe with multiple columns matching keys

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary that I would like to map onto a current dataframe and create a new column. I have keys in a tuple, which map onto two different columns in my dataframe.

```
dct = {('County', 'State'):'CountyType'}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=['County','State'])
```

I would like to create a new column, `CountyType`, using `dict` to map onto the two columns in `df`. However, doing the following gives me an error. How else could this be done?

```
df['CountyType'] = (list(zip(df.County,df.State)))
df = df.replace({'CountyType': county_type_dict)
```

Comment: Don't name dictionaries `dict`, it overrides a builtin name

Comment: I was curious how to create the dictionary of tuples. It is similar to what jpp's answer has. `yourdict = df.set_index(['County','State'])['CountyType'].to_dict()`

Can read more here too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276588/pandas-create-a-dictionary-with-a-tuple-as-key

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a `MultiIndex` from two series and then map. Data from @ALollz.

```
df['CountyType'] = df.set_index(['County', 'State']).index.map(dct.get)

print(df)

  County  State CountyType
0      A      1        One
1      A      2       None
2      B      1       None
3      B      2        Two
4      B      3      Three
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

how do you overcome this?

Comment: You have to use `index` attribute. i.e. `df.index.map`, not `df.map`.

Comment: thanks. How can I use this line to only fill nans in 'County Type'?

Comment: @FaaizQadri, Not sure - that would be a new question.

Answer (score 5):

If you have the following dictionary with tuples as keys and a `DataFrame` with columns corresponding to the tuple values

```
import pandas as pd
dct = {('A', 1): 'One', ('B', 2): 'Two', ('B', 3): 'Three'}
df = pd.DataFrame({'County': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'State': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]})
```

You can create a `Series` of the tuples from your `df` and then just use `.map()`

```
df['CountyType'] = pd.Series(list(zip(df.County, df.State))).map(dct)
```

Results in

```
  County  State CountyType
0      A      1        One
1      A      2        NaN
2      B      1        NaN
3      B      2        Two
4      B      3      Three
```

Comment: can you use this to only fill nan?
I tried with pd.Series.fillna(), but does not work.