# How do I pass two dataframe column values as keys to a 2-key to one value dictionary and get the result into another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary with two keys for converting between units: key (UnitA, UnitB) -> Multiplier
thus {('PCT', 'PCT'): 1.0, ('PCT', 'PPM'): 10000.0,  etc.)

In my dataframe I have columns 'UnitA', 'UnitB', Multiplier.

How do I pass the values from UnitA and UnitB to the dictionary and put the value into 'Multiplier?

I can do this for a single key-value dictionary myDict {('A':'1), ('B':2)} by:
df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].map(myDict1)

but I can't work out how to pass two column values as two keys:
e.g. df['Multiplier'] = df['UnitA', 'UnitB'].map(myDict2)

Comment: I found this solution which seems to work for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50631799/mapping-python-dictionary-with-multiple-keys-into-dataframe-with-multiple-column

Answer (score 1):

You make a multiindex:

```
df1=df.set_index(["UnitA", "UnitB"])
```

And then

```
my_dict = df1.to_dict()["Multiplier"]
```