# Bucketing based on two columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Assuming we have a dataframe at least two columns and there are two columns we want to use to create a new column. In this case, say both columns are boolean values for a feature and we want a column that buckets the 4 combinations. The labels can be 0 - 3 but do not have to be as maybe F,F could have the same bucket as T,T. How can this be coded up generally in Pandas? I'd be very interested in knowing how to generalize this to non-boolean values such as floats or ints. Also having specific labels would be helpful i.e. instead of 0-3 maybe "prospecting", "sale", "pending", "closed".

An example dataframe of what I want could be...

| feature_1 | feature_2 | feature_1_2_bucket |
| --- | --- | --- |
| False | True | 3 |
| True | False | 1 |
| False | False | 2 |
| True | True | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50631799/mapping-python-dictionary-with-multiple-keys-into-dataframe-with-multiple-column) should help:

```
>>> a = pd.DataFrame({"names":['a','b','c'], "v1": np.random.choice([True,False], size=3),
 "v2":np.random.choice([True,False], size=3)})
>>> a
  names     v1     v2
0     a  False   True
1     b   True  False
2     c  False   True

>>> b = {(True, True): 0, (True, False):1, (False, True): 2, (False, False): 3}
>>> a['v3'] = a.set_index(['v1', 'v2']).index.map(b.get)
>>> a
  names     v1     v2  v3
0     a  False   True   2
1     b   True  False   1
2     c  False   True   2
```

To get other values in `v3` just change the values in the dictionary `b`.